# Can I replace the IO driver for printf at runtime using gcc?

Tags: glibc

I'm using gcc 4.8.4 on an ARM from TI.  I want to route printf() and fgets() to my UART driver.  I'm looking for a functional interface to install a file IO driver.  But the GCC docs say "Don’t try to create your own objects of type FILE; let the library do it."  I can't imagine I need to rebuild glibc to change this?  Anyone know an example of creating my own FILE structure?

I can see a definition used for FILE (__sFILE in reent.h).  Seems dangerous just to create one and use it.  But maybe?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to route printf() and fgets() to my UART driver.

Are you perhaps looking for

```
freopen("/dev/uart", "r", stdin);
freopen("/dev/uart", "w", stdout);
```

[Documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3p.html).

Comment: Not so much.  I'm wondering how to create /dev/uart.  This isn't linux, but it is glibc.

Comment: The `/dev/uart` is something your UART kernel driver creates, and the `freopen` associates `stdout` with it. If your question is about the *kernel* part, then you've asked completely wrong question.

Comment: That helps.  It's often hard to get a good answer when you ask the wrong question.  :-)  Since it's not a Linux kernel, I'll have to dig into what TI does.